# How to get better performances when using UNION SELECT and filters on HANA DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hana

Does HANA DB do optimization on a query when I declare WHERE condition?
For example, I'd like to know where can I get better performance or if both options are the same:

If the WHERE condition is the same, should it be in each UNION SELECT or can I use it at end of the query?

Option 1:

```
SELECT DATA.TABLE_NAME, DATA.DATE FROM (
SELECT
    'TABLE1' AS TABLE_NAME,
    DATE
    FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE1" TABLE1
    WHERE DATE >= '2018-12-01' AND DATE <= '2018-12-31'
UNION SELECT
    'TABLE2' AS TABLE_NAME,
    DATE
    FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE2" TABLE2
    WHERE DATE >= '2018-12-01' AND DATE <= '2018-12-31'
UNION SELECT
    'TABLE3' AS TABLE_NAME,
    DATE
    FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE3" TABLE3
    WHERE DATE >= '2018-12-01' AND DATE <= '2018-12-31'
) DATA
WHERE DATA.DATE >= '2018-12-01' AND DATA.DATE <= '2018-12-31'
```

Does the database optimize the query with the where conditions or should I mention the where condition on each SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question: Yes, SAP HANA optimizes the query and will try to push down the outer WHERE condition if possible.

The easiest way to check on that is to use `EXPLAIN PLAN` and check whether the filters have been applied before or after the UNION was processed.

Comment: Thanks. If so, I will use only one WHERE condition at the outer select.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tables have no duplicates, you can use `UNION ALL`.  The subquery is also unnecessary:

```
SELECT 'TABLE1' AS TABLE_NAME, DATE
FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE1" TABLE1
WHERE DATE >= '2018-12-01' AND DATE <= '2018-12-31'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE2' AS TABLE_NAME, DATE
FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE2" TABLE2
WHERE DATE >= '2018-12-01' AND DATE <= '2018-12-31'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE3' AS TABLE_NAME, DATE
FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE3" TABLE3
WHERE DATE >= '2018-12-01' AND DATE <= '2018-12-31';
```

`UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  You have no duplicates *between* tables because of the first column, so use `UNION ALL` instead.

If your tables do have duplicates, then add an index on `DATE` to each of them, and use `SELECT DISTINCT` with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'TABLE1' AS TABLE_NAME, DATE
FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE1" TABLE1
WHERE DATE >= '2018-12-01' AND DATE <= '2018-12-31'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'TABLE2' AS TABLE_NAME, DATE
FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE2" TABLE2
WHERE DATE >= '2018-12-01' AND DATE <= '2018-12-31'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'TABLE3' AS TABLE_NAME, DATE
FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE3" TABLE3
WHERE DATE >= '2018-12-01' AND DATE <= '2018-12-31';
```

The index will be used for the `SELECT DISTINCT` and you won't be incurring overhead to remove non-existent duplicates between tables.

Comment: @András . . . That is the point of the answer.  Because the first columns are different, there is no need to remove duplicates *across* tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answers

Comment: The assumption that an index will be used if present really is just that, an assumption. For column store tables additional index are used to lookup record only if that looks beneficial to the optimizers.